# in ember v2 router why isn't controllerFor() giving a reference to this controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Here's the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/inconduit/hf7XM/10/

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Click on 'Go to Posts'.
- Click the 'controllerFor' text, it won't clear the list.
- Click the global reference text, it will clear the list.

It seems that the controller reference returned by `controllerFor()` is not actually the `PostsIndexController`?  Why is that?

I hacked it in the `setupController()` hook of the Route to set a global reference to that controller on App, and when I set the content on that reference to a new array in `emptyList2()`, the list correctly clears in the template.

Am I using `controllerFor()` wrong? Or misunderstanding what it's returning? Is it a scoping issue?  Please help me out.

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController : function(controller,model) {
    controller.set('content',['one','two','three']);
    App.postsIndexController = controller;
  }
});

// receives the {{action}} from the template
App.PostsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  emptyList : function() {
    this.controllerFor('postsIndex').set('content',Ember.A());
  },
  emptyList2 : function() {
    App.postsIndexController.set('content',Ember.A());
  }  
});
```

Comment: to be clear - setting the global variable App.postsIndexController = controller; is a hack.  i only did this to test if calling set('content',Ember.A()) on the controller actually worked when i had a reference to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tldr: replace `controllerFor('postsIndex')` with `controllerFor('posts.index')`

---

The emptyList2 fx was working because you'd set the `App.postsIndexController` constant to be whatever controller instance got handed to `setupController`.

I think more important than how to fix this is how to debug these kinda problems. Here's what I did:

Opened the JS console while running that JS fiddle. After clicking the posts links but before trying to empty the list, I ran the following:

```
Em.keys(App.__container__.cache.dict)
["application:main", "router:main", "route:application", "route:index", "controller:application", "template:application", "controller:index", "template:index", "route:posts", "route:posts.index", "controller:posts", "template:posts", "controller:posts.index", "template:posts.index"]
```

Then after clicking the emptyList action, tried again:

```
Em.keys(App.__container__.cache.dict)
["application:main", "router:main", "route:application", "route:index", "controller:application", "template:application", "controller:index", "template:index", "route:posts", "route:posts.index", "controller:posts", "template:posts", "controller:posts.index", "template:posts.index", "controller:postsIndex"]
```

See how there are now 2 cached instances of App.PostsIndexController: controller:postsIndex and controller:posts.index

Then I added a few console.logs to the jsFiddle to see what instances were being referenced. From there it was pretty easy to make the fix. Since Ember adds a toString() method to every object it is pretty easy to see what is going on. For example:

```
controllerFor("postsIndex").toString()
<App.PostsIndexController:ember218>
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/Aa2WX/2/

Comment: thanks a ton michael, and it's especially helpful to see your debugging method.  much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the controllerFor option has been deprecated and replaced with the needs API. Check out this blog post: http://www.kaspertidemann.com/auto-synthesized-controllers-when-using-the-needs-api-in-ember-js/